# for em onload JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loop, for

Qual o motivo de meu for não chegar a chamar a função `showSeatStatus(i);`?

```
window.onload = function() {
    //Conecta os eventos de imagem de poltrona
    for (var i = 0; i < tamanhoMatriz; i++) {
        document.getElementById("acento"+i).onclick = function(evt) { //ELE PASSA AQUI
            showSeatStatus(i); // ELE NÃO PASSA AQUI
        };
    }
};
```

se eu fizer sem o for, ele roda normal, assim:

```
 document.getElementById("acento"+0).onclick = function(evt) {
            showSeatStatus(0);
        };
```

O problema é que ele não esta chamando a função `showSeatStatus(i);` em momento algum.

Comment: Se você der um alert dentro da função onclick ele alerta?, Acredito que o problema seja que a função onclick é um listener ou seja ela ficaria esperando a ação do click, ai quando carrega o for vai girar mas se o click não for efetuado não chamará a showSeatStatus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema tem a ver com [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) que faz com que todas as funções de `click` estejam relacionadas com a mesma variável `i`, e por isso com o seu valor final.

Para contornar este efeito basta trocar `var` por [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), que força com que a variável apenas exista naquele bloco, que foi uma das ideias por trás desta nova sintaxe:

```
for (let i = 0..
```

Exemplo:

```js
const tamanhoMatriz = 4;

window.onload = function() {
  //Conecta os eventos de imagem de poltrona
  for (let i = 0; i < tamanhoMatriz; i++) {
    document.getElementById("acento" + i).onclick = function(evt) { //ELE PASSA AQUI
      showSeatStatus(i); // ELE NÃO PASSA AQUI
    };
  }
};

function showSeatStatus(indice){
  console.log("Status em " + indice);
}
```

```html
<div id="acento0">div1</div>
<div id="acento1">div2</div>
<div id="acento2">div3</div>
<div id="acento3">div4</div>
```

Comment: Eu tava escrevendo sobre isso, mas você foi mais rápido (e eu não teria escrito tão bem). +1.

Comment: Funcionou, porem eu não entendi o funcionamento :/, fui pesquisar sobre clousers e let, eu entendi que o let só roda em escopo de bloco. porem não entendi o clousers nesse código.

Comment: @NicolasGuilhermeMatheus `closure` é o mecanismo de a função guardar os valores que precisa para mais tarde executar, valores que só existem naquele momento, como o `i` em `showSeatStatus(i);`. Lembre-se que quando a função executa, bastante tempo depois, teoricamente o `i` já nem existiria.

Comment: @Isac, de primeiro momento ainda não está claro pra mim, mas pode deixar que vou entender com o tempo, iniciei meus estudos sobre JS recentemente. Agradeço por me explicar como funciona, e pelas palavras **closure** e **let**, que já me adicionou um conhecimento a  mais, como por exemplo, em JS você pode atribuir um valor a uma variável não declarada e depois declara-la, que mesmo assim o código funcionará, em tempo de execução o JS manda para cima todas as variáveis.